# Blender rigify problem / automatic weight problem

Tags: rigging, unity

I am beginner to blender. I am trying to create a rig to my character which I will import to Unity later on. I watched these videos ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DS885Sk1gSs), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnP54h3x6_Y&t=1213s)) to create a rig but I faced a major issue when I try to pose the character.

The character looks like left leg and right leg are stuck together.
With my limited knowledge and Google skill, I am hard stuck.

[image: Behavior of leg is very moving weird]

As I control right leg or left leg, the opposite leg moves together.

[image: here is the second pic.]

[image: this is the result that I want]

and this is the behavior of the leg that I intended.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: It looks to me that the Automatic Weights did a poor job on your mesh. Try this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150395/rig-is-moving-other-parts-of-my-mesh-for-no-reason?rq=1 . You may need to manually adjust the vertex weights in vertex paint mode.