Why are parts of the model stuck together?
So I’m new to Blender and I’m working towards animation, but for right now I’m stuck. I got some models from the web and removed the existing rig and plugged the model into Mixamo so I could use that rig and everything else seems to work fine. I’ve checked the weight paint and reassigned vertex groups but it still happens. I’ve checked the vertices in edit mode and they do overlap but even when I reassign them, the model is still stuck together


Here is the blend file

Edit: After merging the vertices by distance, there are some faces that got deleted. How do I fix this?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

There's no way we can help you with that unless you present more details like sharing your blend file https://blend-exchange.com. Here someone had the same problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251298/blender-rigify-problem-automatic-weight-problem and obviously it is that some vertices are assigned to the wrong vertex groups.

There are a lot of duplicated vertices. These are vertices that are in the same position or at least very close to each other. To remove them, edit the mesh, select all verts, and merge them by distance (key M). In the status bar, you will see there are 27k duplicated vertices removed. The weights are messed up now but you can fix them when you select the mesh, then the armature, and parent it again with automatic weights (Cltr+P).

Thanks! That worked, but now there are holes in the model in preview and render. What's the cause for that and how do I solve it?

Oh sorry, I've noticed this but forgot to mention it. It's because the material is transparent ("Model001_Material007"). Check the material. You will see the Image Texture node ("gokussj_detail.png.002") is connected to the Principal BSDF's Alpha slot. Because the alpha channel of the image is pure black, all faces are transparent. (0=black=transparent, 1=white=opaque). Just cut the connection or paint over the image (A=alpha channel, not RGB). I think the duplicated vertices/faces are actually a detail layer that adds more detail lines to the pants.

If you want to keep the detail layer I would separate it into a separate object. With the L key, you can select the mesh parts. Then do the weight paint for the base model and transfer the weights to the detail layer (Ctrl+L > Transfer Mesh Data > Vertex Groups, all, by name) or use a Data Transfer modifier. (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275931/107598, bottom half of the text)

Okay, I’m not worried about the detail layer right now. Would you further elaborate? I painted over the image in the image editor but the transparent faces just turned black, also when I disconnected the image.

Yes, that's because the transparent faces have a different material with Alpha set to 0 and base color is black. The easiest way to fix this is probably to assign the same material (“Model001_Material002”) to the transparent faces that the non-transparent neighboring faces have. https://i.sstatic.net/MB9MzkAp.png <- (1) select the surface, (2) check the material, (3) change it, (4) assign it. The color will still be different. That's because of the UV map. The transparent faces are on their own UV island.

To fix the UVs: (5) Go to UV editor, select all verts (key A) in Edit mode (3D viewport), then select all UV islands in the UV editor and press key Numpad period (or View > Frame Selected) to see them. The UV islands are far far in the top left corner (6). Move the transparent face next to its non-transparent neighbor. You also can move it down to the image so you can better see the color (the color is also shown on the model in 3D viewport, Material Preview mode). Keep in mind that the face must be in the right pos for the normal map else it's darker. You haven't included it so I can't tell

one more note: Your model seems to be a Guilty Gear style model. There is another question about the Guilty Gear Style UV map here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/323864/107598. It might be interesting for you, read the comments and watch the linked videos. I hope that helps :)

Thanks so much! I’ve been working on the model here and there and everything is going smoothly. Only problem now is that select faces are like linked to a different image when I try to change them.
