How to make a UV map for a Guilty Gear Style character? (Square UV Mapping)
Does anyone know how to make a map like this for my character? It's similar to the game Guilty Gear, which was developed by Arc System Works.

I tried to search but I didn't find anything I needed.
I tried to use Smart UV Project but it turns out it's wrong:


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

The UV unwrap for the texture map that you show is very very unusual and simply not possible to do unless you have some experience with UV unwrapping. The UV seams on the model are determined by where you want inner painted lines to appear on the character. After UV unwrapping the outer edges of each of the UV islands are aligned to either the X or Y axis in the UV space, pinned in place then UV unwrapped a second time. This is done so that inner lines that will appear on the textured character will be clean, sharp  and with no jagged edges due to aliasing.

This form of UV unwrapping and texturing was used in Guilty Gear Xrd and a basic explanation of the technique can be found in this video at 24:16 and 38.47 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhGjCzxJV3E  A little more about this method can be found here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkHe29O6aOU This Video may be more interesting for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okB8EUxPTKs

Another video by Royal Skies on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEH51tkAle4

I’m voting to close this question because this is a basic Blender function rather than a unique problem, and is discussed directly in the Blender manual.

This is a very particular form of UV unwrapping which by definition makes it a unique problem.  :)  Yes the OP needs to first understand basic UV unwrapping before they can tackle such a project but I don't think that is a reason to make it an invalid question.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74041/how-to-perfectly-align-uv-coordinates-automatically/
